# Does we always have to first build catkin_workspace and then only build the catkin_package present in the src of catkin_workspace?

Tags: ros, catkin-make, catkin, packages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I was reading ROS tutorials page on creating and building package in which I came across how to build the ROS packages. In the page it is shown that first the author has build the catkin workspace using catkin_make command and then he/her has build the beginner_tutorials package present in the src directory of the catkin_ws using the same command. So I want to know that whether we always I have to follow the above mention steps or we can directly build the catkin packages as shown in the tutorials inside the catkin_ws.

Links:- http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage
http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/BuildingPackages

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254819/does-we-always-have-to-first-build-catkin_workspace-and-then-only-build-the-catkin_package-present-in-the-src-of-catkin_workspace-?/) by [a443](https://answers.ros.org/users/29219/a443/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2017-02-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Everytime you need to build your packages, only thing you need to do is to run `catkin_make` in root of your catkin workspace. That's it.

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2017-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1